# Webstorm - why does Webstorm display HTTP requests twice in console

Tags: node.js, express, webstorm

[image]

Is it expected that Webstorm show all HTTP requests twice in my console or is there something very wrong with my node.js Express app?

If I run it from the command line, it also logs HTTP requests twice

[image]

Comment: If you run your server outside of Webstorm, does it log the requests only once? I suppose it has nothing to do with WebStorm, you have to check logging configuration of Express.

Comment: yeah, if I run it from the command line, it also logs things twice

Comment: Could you please share your express app code if it is not huge? I want to try it on my side

Comment: You may have something like `app.use(express.logger('dev'));` in your code, or possibly two similar calls. Try to start express in production mode and check whether at least one of your logging outputs goes away. BTW which version of Express do you use?

Comment: hi @Hüseyin the code is here: https://github.com/the1mills/node_sports_lineup?files=1

Comment: is that feature gone? I can't access this RUN > Node shell in Webstorm 2020.1.3

Answer (score 1):

All the requests are doubled due to favicon request. You can disable that favicon requests by using following interceptor;

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    if(req.url != "/favicon.ico"){
        next();
    }
});
```

Simply all requests are intercepted and if any request url matches with `/favicon.ico` will be skipped

Comment: This answer is not correct IMO. It's more likely that it has something to do with logging. There is only one request (not favicon) and the same request is logged twice.

Comment: sure that makes sense, but what setting it would it be in logging?

Comment: @Hüseyin, I tried this code - it does not appear to be a favicon issue